# C# comparing collections

Tags: c#, collections

I'm new to C# and need some help with comparing collections. I have two `List<string>`
collections with their contents as below:

Collection Old: 
{"AAA","BBB","CCC"}

Collection New: 
{"BBB","CCC","DDD"}

I want to get a collection like below:

Collection Final:
{"AAA", "Remove"; "BBB", "Keep"; "CCC", "Keep"; "DDD", "Add"}

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you only care about what's added, removed, and kept? You don't care about changes in ordering?

Comment: should it actually read {"AAA","Remove","BBB","Remove","CCC","Remove","DDD", "Add"}

Comment: How do you see `"AAA"` and `"Remove"` being grouped together? Tuples? `KeyValuePair`s? Just one going after another?

Comment: @Woot4Moo, that doesn't make any sense. BBB and CCC weren't removed -- they're still there in Collection New.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            var oldList = new List<String>() {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC"};
            var newList = new List<String>() {"BBB", "CCC", "DDD"};

            var diffDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var oldEntry in oldList)
            {
                diffDictionary.Add(oldEntry, "Remove");
            }

            foreach (var newEntry in newList)
            {
                if (diffDictionary.ContainsKey(newEntry))
                {
                    diffDictionary[newEntry] = "Keep";
                }
                else
                {
                    diffDictionary.Add(newEntry, "Add");
                }
            }

            foreach (var dDico in diffDictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Key: ", dDico.Key, " Value: ", dDico.Value));
            }
```

Answer (score 8):

`old.Except(new)` will give you those items to remove

`new.Except(old)` will give you items to add

`old.Intersect(new)` will give you items to keep

(This is assuming you don't mind using the System.Linq namespace)

Or if you prefer, you can consider each item individually and check the existence in each list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to do this...

at the end, each element in the dictionary will tell you how many items of each kind were removed or added.

It will indicate this with a count, not a simple 3 state flag... that is because you may have added or removed repeated items... what if you insert 3 `AAA`'s in the second collection.

```
        string[] col1 = new string[] { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
        string[] col2 = new string[] { "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" };

        Dictionary<string, int> colDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var item in col1)
        {
            int num;
            if (colDic.TryGetValue(item, out num))
                colDic[item] = num - 1;
            else
                colDic[item] = -1;
        }

        foreach (var item in col2)
        {
            int num;
            if (colDic.TryGetValue(item, out num))
                colDic[item] = num + 1;
            else
                colDic[item] = 1;
        }
```

The end result will look like this:

```
AAA = -1
BBB = 0
CCC = 0
DDD = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In 1 line (sort of)!

```
string[] colOld = {"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
string[] colNew = {"BBB","CCC","DDD"};

dynamic colALL = (from o in colOld.Union(colNew)
                  select new {Value = o, Action = 
                              colOld.Any(s => s == o) ? 
                                  colNew.Any(s => s == o) ? "Keep" : "Remove" 
                              : "Add"
                           }).ToList();
```

Note: This is a developer fusion conversionof the below vb.net which does work - I've not had chance to test the c# version:

```
 Dim colOld() As String = {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC"}
    Dim colNew() As String = {"BBB", "CCC", "DDD"}

    Dim colALL = (From o As String In colOld.Union(colNew) _
                    Select New With {.Value = o, .Action = _
                                     If(colOld.Any(Function(s) s = o), _
                                        If(colNew.Any(Function(s) s = o), "Keep", "Remove"), _
                                        "Add")}).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sequences)
{
    return sequences.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

you should be able to write:

```
static readonly string Remove = "Remove";
static readonly string Keep = "Keep";
static readonly string Add = "Add";

var result = Concat
(
    old.Except(new).Select(x => new { x, Remove }), 
    old.Intersect(new).Select(x => new { x, Keep }), 
    new.Except(old).Select(x => new { x, Add })
);
```

Of course you can use the built-in `Enumerable.Concat` method but I find mine more elegant.